# OpenCV run-time error while calibrating camera in line calibratecamera

Tags: c++, opencv, runtime-error, calibration

I wrote a calibration code as bellow:

```
int numBoards = 20;
int numCornersHor=6;
int numCornersVer=9;
int numSquares = numCornersHor * numCornersVer;
cv::Size board_sz = cv::Size(numCornersHor, numCornersVer);

std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f> > object_points;
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f> > image_points;
std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
std::vector<cv::Point3f> obj;
    for(int j=0;j<numSquares;j++)
        obj.push_back(cv::Point3f(j/numCornersHor, j%numCornersHor, 0.0f));

int successes=0;
```

After initialization of useful variables, I get frames from webcam and store it in buffer.

```
    while(successes<numBoards)
    {        
        unsigned char* buffer=eyeCamera->getFrame();
        cv::Mat rawImg=cv::Mat(cv::Size(widthCam,heightCam),CV_8UC4, buffer,cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);
        cv::Mat grayImg;
        cv::cvtColor(rawImg,grayImg,CV_BGR2GRAY);

        bool found = findChessboardCorners(rawImg, board_sz, corners,
                                           CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS);
        if(found)
        {
            cv::cornerSubPix(grayImg, corners, cv::Size(11, 11), cv::Size(-1, -1),
                             cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 1.1));
            cv::drawChessboardCorners(grayImg, board_sz, corners, found);
        }

        cv::imshow("win2", grayImg);
```

Everything is ok so far.I show grayImg and chessboard corners are painted.

```
        int key = cv::waitKey(1);
        if(key==27)
            return;

        if(key==' ' && found!=0)
        {
          image_points.push_back(corners);
          object_points.push_back(obj);

          successes++;

          if(successes>=numBoards)
              break;
        }

    }

    cv::Mat intrinsic = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    cv::Mat distCoeffs= cv::Mat(8, 1, CV_64F);
    std::vector<cv::Mat> rvecs;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> tvecs;
    intrinsic.at<double>(0,0) = 1.0;

    int widthCam=640; 
    int heightCam=480;
```

object_points and image_points are filled with 54 elements ~ 9 * 6

```
    cv::calibrateCamera(object_points, image_points, cv::Size(widthCam,heightCam), intrinsic, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
```

I'm using Qt creator. I always get run-time error while calling the last line: calibrateCamera()

Edit: I tried the same code with `cvCalibrateCamera2` and again i got the same error. I provide opencv Exeption:

```
OpenCV error: Bad argument (the output array of translation vectors must be 3-channel
1xn or nx1 array or 1-channel nx3 array, where n is the bumber of views) in
cvCalibrateCamera2, file F:\OpenCV\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\calibration.cpp,line 1506
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exeption'
```

I am using 10 snapshot and my defined rvec and tvec are as follows:

```
CvMat* rvec  = cvCreateMat(10,3,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* tvec  = cvCreateMat(10,3,CV_32FC1);
```

Can anyone help me solve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: We will answer when we do. There's no need to add comments bellow your question, it won't speed things up. Sometimes it can take days/weeks before somebody replies if your question is too specific. There are few people that contribute to the OpenCV tag around here.

Comment: If you have OpenCV sources you can compile it, install the debug version on your system, and then debug your application to trace `cv::calibrateCamera()` and find out which line in the OpenCV source code is crashing.

Comment: okay, didn't see that code before. r vec is a rotation matrix, so it is 3x3 (cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_64F)), while tVec is a translation matrix, its supposed to be 3x1 or 1x3 (cvCreateMat(3,1, CV_64F) Does that help?

Comment: Not yet! Always crashing

Answer (score 0):

Okay, tried this now locally on my system, turns out that the definition of rVecs and tVecs was actually differently from what I expected it to be.

```
CvMat* rVecs = cvCreateMat( 1, 1, CV_32FC3 );
CvMat* tVecs = cvCreateMat( 1, 1, CV_32FC3 );
```

did the job for me.

Comment: Not worked again. Did it worked with cvCalibrateCamera2 for you? I had the same problem while using Rodrigues() too.

Comment: I used cvCalibrateCamera2(), yes.

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet plz? maybe other thing is wrong!

Comment: I have the code actually for a stereo camera pair only, and I injected the code for the single camera. It can be found at http://pastebin.com/QFqdfdVM 
Your code is at line 117. Note that I do the calibration once per frame only, thus I do not accumulate any frame data.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if 
 `CvMat* tvec  = cvCreateMat(3,10,CV_32FC1);`
 will help.

also, try 
 `CvMat* tvec  = cvCreateMat(1,10,CV_32FC3);`